# ps output with iso date format?

Tags: shell, date, ps

I'd like to sort this output by `lstart` (start of process):

```
ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd
```

Is there a way to output lstart in ISO format like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

But sorting alone does not solve it. I really would like to have ISO date format.

Comment: Why does `lstart` have such a wierd format. Its close to RFC 2822 but with year on the end.

Answer (score 16):

> Is there a way to output `lstart` in ISO format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`?

With **`awk`** + **`date`** cooperation:

```
ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd --sort=start_time | awk '{ 
       cmd="date -d\""$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5"\" +\047%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\047"; 
       cmd | getline d; close(cmd); $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; printf "%s\n",d$0 }'
```

---

Alternative approach using *ps* `etimes` keyword(elapsed time since the process was started, in seconds):

```
ps -eo etimes,pid,cmd --sort=etimes | awk '{ 
       cmd="date -d -"$1"seconds +\047%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\047"; 
       cmd | getline d; close(cmd); $1=""; printf "%s\n",d$0 }'
```

- `date -d -"$1"seconds` - difference between the current timestamp and `elapsed` time, will give the *timestamp* value of the process

Comment: Is there no easier way?

Comment: If you use ps format `etimes` instead of `lstart` you get the elapsed time in seconds which is a bit easier to pass into `date -d -999seconds`.

Comment: @meuh, yes, that would be a bit shorter, I've made an update

Comment: @guettli, can't call it easier, but you got a bit shorter way

Comment: And check if your `ps` has `--no-headers` or you can adjust the awk to have `NR>1` at the front, or else just run with `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 4):

You can sort with:

```
ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd --sort=start_time
```

Comment: Thank you, I extended my question. I want iso date format, too.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `lstart` is not one of the standard Unix `ps` columns.

Not all systems have one, and the output varies between implementations and potentially between locales.

For instance, on FreeBSD or with the `ps` from `procps-ng` (as typically found on non-embedded Linux-based systems) and the `C` locale, you'll get:

```
Wed Nov  1 12:36:15 2017
```

On macOS:

```
Wed  1 Nov 12:36:15 2017
```

Also, since, it doesn't give you the GMT offset, the output is ambiguous in timezones that implement DST  (where there's one hour during the year where the same dates occur twice) and do not always sort chronologically.

Here, you could force the times to be UTC and use `perl`'s `Date::Manip` module to parse the date in a way that understands different natural formats:

```
(export TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C
  ps -A -o lstart= -o pid= -o args= |
    perl -MDate::Manip -lpe '
      s/^(\s*\S+){5}/UnixDate(ParseDate($&), "%Y-%m-%dT%T+00:00")/e' |
    sort
)
```

Or with `ksh93` which also recognises those date formats:

```
(export TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C
  unset -v IFS
  ps -A -o lstart= -o pid= -o args= |
    while read -r a b c d e rest; do
      printf '%(%FT%T+00:00)T %s\n' "$a $b $c $d $e" "$rest"
    done
)
```

(beware it strips trailing blanks from each line)

Or with `zsh` and GNU `date`:

```
(export LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0
  (){
    paste -d '\0' <(cut -c1-24 < $1 | date -f- --iso-8601=s) \
                  <(cut -c25-  < $1) | sort
  } =(ps -A -o lstart= -o pid= -o args=)
)
```

Or with `bash` (or `zsh`) on Linux only and with GNU `date`:

```
(export LC_ALL=C TZ=UTC0
  {
    paste -d '\0' <(cut -c1-24 | date -f- --iso-8601=s) \
                  <(cut -c25- < /dev/stdin) | sort
  } <<< "$(ps -A -o lstart= -o pid= -o args=)"
)
```

Also beware that the process start time is not necessarily the same as the last time that process executed a command as processes can an generally do run more than one command in their lifetime (those that don't are generally those that never execute a command). In other words, it doesn't necessarily correspond to the time the command (`args` field, the standard equivalent of `cmd`) was started.

```
$ sh -c 'sleep 4; exec sleep 123' & sleep 234 & sleep 5
[1] 9380
[2] 9381
$ (export TZ=UTC0 LC_ALL=C; ps -o lstart,pid,args | perl -MDate::Manip -lpe 's/^(\s*\S+){5}/UnixDate(ParseDate($&), "%Y-%m-%dT%T+00:00")/e')

2017-10-30T17:21:06+00:00  3071 zsh
2017-11-01T15:47:48+00:00  9380 sleep 123
2017-11-01T15:47:48+00:00  9381 sleep 234
```

See how `sleep 123` is seen as having been started at the same time as `sleep 234` even though it was started 4 seconds later. That's because that 9388 process was initially running `sh` (and waiting 4 seconds for `sleep 4`) before it executed `sleep 123` (and before that, it was running `zsh` code as it was forked by my interactive shell, so at different points in time, for that process, you would have seen in the `ps` output: `zsh`, then `sh`, then `sleep`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have more questions than before. I thought there is an easy and simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation with higher performance (does not need to execute a new process per line, sorts oldest process as the last):

```
ps -eo etimes,pid,args --sort=etimes | awk 'BEGIN{now=systime()} {$1=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", now-$1); print $0}'
```

and this allows pretty easily to change column ordering, too. For example pid, etimes, arg. And to primary sort by start time and secondary by pid, you can do something like:

```
ps -eo pid,etimes,args --sort=-etimes,pid | awk 'BEGIN{now=systime()} {$2=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", now-$2); print $0}'
```

(the `etimes` must be sorted in reverse because it's actually count of seconds in the past for the process start time, this should match the actual execution order of the processes except if PID counter overflows on the same second for multiple processes).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem outdated. Just pass the option  `--date-format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'`.

This is available in the latest versions of `procps-ng` (Linux's standard).